# Deleting my downvoted, but answered question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I asked a question on Stack Exchange that got downvoted multiple times, but I can't delete it since people have answered it. What should I do?

Comment: TL;DR: flag for moderator attention, explain why you want it removed/dissociated from your account. (See the "If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?" section)

Comment: Why do you want to delete your question? If it's a reasonable condition, you can flag the question, like what @Jenayah said. Moderators will be the judge on whether is should be deleted or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I did, you can flag your question, hit the flag button, then hit the "in need of moderator invention" button, then a text widget will show up, then you can write there saying that you want to delete the question, then it may take few hours, depends on your luck, and the moderators will either decline it, or make the flag "helpful" flag.

Like I had the post just like yours (on MSE though), and I flagged it, and the moderator made it as a "helpful" flag, and deleted my question, so it worked.

Try your luck!

**Edit:**

I realized, you maybe shouldn't delete the question, because you actually got an upvote on it, gained 5 reputation points, and 2 from accepting someone. If you remove that question, you'll have only 1 reputation point, and you have that much because you first got the downvotes and then you got the downvote, so when you have 1, you can't go any lower than 1, so basically, in reputation, this question is 1 upvote and 0 downvotes.

So after all, you really shouldn't delete your question, since you earned reputation from it.